# Form field alignment issues using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**PROBLEM:**

I'm having some alignment issues with this form.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
  .form-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.verification-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.verification-form .form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

.verification-form .form-group:nth-child(3) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-group label {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #484343;
  margin-left: 10px;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.form-group input {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  flex: 3;
  border: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
  transition: border-color 0.3s;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#required::after {
  content: "*";
  color: #f06d41;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.form-group input:hover {
  border-color: #aa2c2f;
  outline: 0;
}

.form-group input:focus {
  border-color: #aa2c2f;
  outline: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 28px !important;
  height: 28px !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  flex: none;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-width: 2px;
  transition: border-color 0.3s;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  content: "✔";
  color: #aa2c2f;
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="verification-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>FIRST</label>
      <input id="firstName" type="" name="firstName" value="" required />
      <label>LAST</label>
      <input id="lastName" type="" name="lastName" value="" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="required">
      <label>EMAIL</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>PHONE</label>
      <input id="phone" type="" name="phone" value="" required />
      <label class="sms-label">SMS<br />OPT IN</label>
      <input id="sms" type="checkbox" name="sms" value="" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="required">
      <label>STREET<br />ADDRESS</label>
      <input id="address" type="text" name="address" value="" required />
    </div>
    <div class="legend">
      <p>
        <sub>*</sub>Required field
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the form looks wonky.

I feel like this is the culprit:

```
.form-group input {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  flex: 3;
  border: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
  transition: border-color 0.3s;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

I would like the form to align properly where all fields in a single column are the same size and aligned. I also want the rows with two form fields to be even with rows that have only one field.

I've tried excluding `flex:3` with a static width, however, this is not the solution. Would appreciate any help in making this look better.

**EDIT:** Also open to a solution using CSS grid.

Comment: I think `grid` will be a better way to solve that, instead of `flex`, as you have several column distributions along the rows, it would be easier.

Comment: Why do you really need flexbox at all? `input` and `label` are both `inline` elements to start with.

Comment: @Leo Thanks, I was literally just looking up a solution using grid. - I'm definitely open to a grid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in your code. You should use flex for the paten div for the form and if you give witdh:100% to the input fileds it will fit the container of its own. So here the html and css for your form.

Html:

```
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="verification-form">
    <div class="form-group" >
      <label class="required">FIRST</label>
      <input id="firstName" type="" name="firstName" value=""  required />
      <label class="required">LAST</label>
      <input id="lastName" type="" name="lastName" value=""  required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="required">
      <label class="required">EMAIL</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value=""   required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="required">PHONE</label>
      <input id="phone" type="" name="phone" value=""   required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="sms-label required">SMS OPTION</label>
      <input id="sms" type="checkbox" name="sms" value=""  required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="required">
      <label class="required" >STREET ADDRESS</label>
      <input id="address" type="text" name="address" value=""   required />
    </div>
    <div class="legend">
      <p>
        <sub class="required"></sub>Required field
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.verification-form .form-group:nth-child(3) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.form-group {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  text-align:start;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  max-width:320px;
  padding:10px;
}
.form-group.row {
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.form-group label {
  text-align: start;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #484343;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.form-group input {
  width:100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  flex: 3;
  border: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
  transition: border-color 0.3s;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.required::after {
  content: "*";
  color: #f06d41;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-group input:hover {
  border-color: #aa2c2f;
  outline: 0;
}

.form-group input:focus {
  border-color: #aa2c2f;
  outline: 0;
}
.legend {
  margin-left:20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 28px !important;
  height: 28px !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  flex: none;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-width: 2px;
  transition: border-color 0.3s;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  content: "✔";
  color: #aa2c2f;}
```